# Getting a result from a modal window in pygtk

Tags: python, modal-dialog, pygtk

I need to open a new window from my applications main window. This new window need to be
modal, I need to be able to get a result from the modal window based on user interaction with it.

I have figured out how to make the window modal. But I can't figure out how to return a result from the modal window and pass it back to the main window when user close the modal window.

Comment: How are your app's threads structured?  Do you have a main thread separate from the gtk thread, or do you pass control completely to the gtk main loop?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to make your window a gtk.Dialog and launch it via the run() method.  This is designed to do exactly what you are looking for.

See [pygtk docs](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkdialog.html#method-gtkdialog--run) for gtk.Dialog.run

Comment: Dialog is a good option although I am not so keen having the default ok and cancel button that comes with a dialog. I have decided to implement an observer pattern to observe changes into the underlying data that the user modify in the modal window, and notify the main window of any changes.